# C# how to read the apache vhosts file

Tags: c#, regex, vhosts

I'm trying to create a basic C# application for managing my Apache vHosts file so i dont have to edit the file raw to setup a new vhost

Now i'm trying to get regex to match the Vhosts but this is not working would some one proivde me a working example

This is what i currently have

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
string regEx = "<VirtualHost .*>.*</VirtualHost>";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(content, regEx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
     MessageBox.Show(match.Value);
}
```

This fails but if i use `string regEx = "<VirtualHost  .*>.*"`
it works to the point it returns the opening vhosts tag but will not return any of the content where it should return every thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your regexp

```
"<VirtualHost [^>]*>([^<]*)</VirtualHost>"
```

EDITED:
Added round brackets around the `[^<]*`, so it would return text between the tags as one of the matches.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly (as you can see im still a noob with regex lol)

Comment: `[^<]*` Won't work for the contents if there is any `<` inside (which will be common e.g. `<directory...`). The lazy-dot-star `.*?` would be appropriate to use here.

Comment: Is there a way to allow support mate?

Comment: According to @ridgeruner it should be written as `<VirtualHost>(.*?)</VirtualHost>`. **Lazy-dot-star**, i.e., `.*?` makes dot to match as little as possible. So, if you write something after **lazy-dot-star**, in our case `</VirtualHost>`, it will match everything but not `</VirtualHost>` as there is a part of expression following **lazy-dot-star*, which matches it. Hopefully my explenation was not too complicated. :)